# Dispose object that has been instantiated as method parameter c#

Tags: c#, parameters, dispose

I have the following classes:

```
private static readonly string ConnectionString = "Dummy";
public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    return Connection;
}

public static SqlDataAdapter GetDataAdapter(string Query)
{
    SqlDataAdapter Adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, GetConnection());
    return Adapt;
}
```

- How do I dispose the SqlConnection object that is instantiated when GetConnection() is passed as parameter in my SqlDataAdapter constructor?
- Will it get disposed automatically when I dispose my Adapt object in the method that called GetDataAdapter()?
- If it's not possible to dispose it, how do you suggest to proceed?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx703tc9.aspx): "SqlDataAdapter opens and closes a SqlConnection if it is not already open. [...] If the SqlConnection is already open, you must explicitly call Close or Dispose to close it."

Comment: unless you put that code within a using(SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString) { };then after using object will get disposed automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

If you dispose your `SqlDataAdapter`  it does not dispose the `SqlConnection` too because its not clear if you want to use the connection again. You have to change your design to get this done.

I suggest to pass the `SqlConnection` to the `GetDataAdapter` function.

#### Sample

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnection()) 
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = GetDataAdapter("YourQuery", connection)) 
        {

        }
        // SqlDataAdapter is disposed
    }
    // SqlConnection is disposed
}

private static readonly string ConnectionString = "Dummy";
public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    return Connection;
}

public static SqlDataAdapter GetDataAdapter(string Query, SqlConnection connection)
{
    SqlDataAdapter Adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, connection);
    return Adapt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the adapter does not dipose the connection. You should change it to this at least:

```
public static SqlDataAdapter GetDataAdapter(SqlConnection connection, string Query)
{
    SqlDataAdapter Adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(Query);
    Adapt.Connection = connection;
    return Adapt;
}
```

and use it like this

```
using (var connection = GetConnection())
using (var adapter = GetAdapter(connection, query))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

This way you are also more flexible by being able to pass some other connection in - in case you need it for some exceptional circustances.