# Will supplying a SQLCommand with a new SQLConnection call Dispose on the new SQL Connection?

Tags: c#

**PREAMBLE**

I understand that normally most SQL calls run thusly

```
using(var cnn = new DbConnection("YOURCONNECTIONSTRINGHERE") 
{
  cnn.Open(); //Open the connection.
  using(var cmd = new DbCommand("YourSQL", cnn)
  {
    cmd.ExecuteScalar; //Or whatever type of execution you want.
  }
}
```

This will properly dispose of both the connection and the command.

**My Question: Will this code properly dispose of both objects?**

```
  using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("YourSQL", new Connection("YOURCONNECTIONSTRINGHERE"))
  {
    cmd.ExecuteScalar; //Or whatever type of execution you want.
  }
```

In reality I'm using a method that provides and opens the connection.

```
public SqlConnection Connection()
{
    var product = new SQLConnection("ConnectionString");
    product.Open();
    return product;
}
```

So at the end of the day the call looks like this:

```
  using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("YourSQL", Connection())
  {
    cmd.ExecuteScalar; //Or whatever type of execution you want.
  }
```

I know the SqlCommand object will be disposed of but will the SQLConnection, created within the using parameter declaration, be disposed of? I've tried running some simple unit tests but it seems inconclusive.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for. If you look at [ExecuteReader()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.8) you'll see there's an overload that takes a [CommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.commandbehavior?view=netframework-4.8) value. One of those behaviors is `CloseConnection` which closes the connection automatically when the `DataReader` is closed.

Comment: `Dispose` won't be called in your code, but eventually object will be destructed. But if you need to call `Dispose` - you can use `using` with your function as well - `using (var conn = Connection()) using (var cmd = ...`

Comment: `using` will only `Dispose()` the resource created/tracked by that `using` statement.  That you happen to create a `Connection` inline and pass it as a parameter does not provide the guarantee of that `using` statement; it's just some ancillary object.  That's why you always see one `using` statement each for the `Connection` and `Command`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dispose object that has been instantiated as method parameter c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765260/dispose-object-that-has-been-instantiated-as-method-parameter-c-sharp) or [Does “using” also dispose objects created in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37836565/150605) or [Does the using statement dispose only the first variable it create?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17317251/150605)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will this code properly dispose of both objects?
>
> ```
> using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("YourSQL", new Connection("YOURCONNECTIONSTRINGHERE"))
> {
>     cmd.ExecuteScalar; //Or whatever type of execution you want.   
> }
> ```

The above code does not call `Dispose()` on the *connection*. The `using` block ensures that `cmd.Dispose()` is called immediately after the execution of the block, but the *connection* remains open. Since the *connection* has no object referencing it, it will be eventually closed/disposed by the Garbage Collector.

If you want to dispose the *Command* and *Connection* immediately, then try:

```
using (var con = Connection()) // <-- GetConnection() would be a better name
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(con)
{
    cmd.ExecuteScalar; 
}
```

Comment: I'm aware that nesting them without brackets would dispose of it. It's a shame that it doesn't close the connection. I'm always looking for places to minimize my code while maintaining efficiency.

Thanks for the explanation. I suppose I'll be nesting it.

Comment: I don't know your use case... if you were using Entity Framework 6, then you could initialize `DbContext` with a connection... `DbContext` constructor has a flag called `contextOwnsConnection` if you set the flag, then disposing `DbContext` would dispose connection too [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-management)... but there is no such flag for `SqlCommand`...

Comment: Good information to have for personal projects but we don't have heavy use of Entity Framework where I work.